# upgrading Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am currently working with Xcode 3.1.3 , i wanted to upgrade it to new version of Xcode 4.0.My question is will i be able to run my older applications which were built on Xcode 3.1.3 on the new version of Xcode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to do so. However PPC support and 10.4 support is dropped on the mac. If you want to play safe, you can install Xcode 4 in a separate location leaving your Xcode 3.1.3 untouched, so you can switch between these two.

The project format of Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 4 is the same.

Comment: It's not actually that simple, in practice I've seen projects failing to compile. In the worst case you'll have to create an empty project in Xcode 4 and move your old project contents into it.

Comment: sorry i did not get what is PPC support ??

Comment: @Mr.Gando well you have to be familiar with the build system that is true, but in principle it works nicely. It of course depends on how many dependencies you set up and if you are using source trees for example.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to install Xcode 4 into another directory. I just installed the latest version yesterday and it offers you this option.  Here is a link [here](http://meachware.blogspot.com/2011/01/xcode-updates.html) about this also.  There is also a StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392855/can-i-run-xcode-3-and-xcode-4-at-the-same-time).  If everything works as you expect you can delete Xcode 3.1.3.  If not, you still have your current version around.