# What version of Xcode should I be using?

Tags: objective-c

My app is fairly close to being submitted for approval.  I would like to make sure I am using the most current version of Xcode that I can.  My Mac's operation system is Mac OS X Version 10.6.8 and I am using Xcode Version 3.2.3.  I have seen that there are Versions 4.0 and 4.1 for Xcode.  Should I be using one of these, or am I good to go?

Comment: Apple doesn't mind if you submit a build that was compiled with Xcode 3.

Comment: XCode 4 is yummy - but you can use 3 fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Xcode 3.2 and 4.0 are supported on Snow Leopard. You can use any of them. Since you already use 3.2 I would recommend that you keep using that version until you find a good time to update to the 4.x series.

It is however a good idea to update to the latest version of Xcode 3.2, which is currently 3.2.6. That way you get the latest bug fixes and updates while staying on the 3.2 branch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I upgraded and everything seems to be working ok.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Xcode 4. You'll want to upgrade to it eventually anyway. Also, it makes it much easier to package up an app and submit it to the App Store. Just make sure you keep your Xcode 3, in case you need it - see here: [Can I run Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392855/can-i-run-xcode-3-and-xcode-4-at-the-same-time)